# Write different datatype values to a file in R

Tags: r

Is it possible to write values of different datatypes to a file in R? Currently, I am using a simple vector as follows:

```
> vect = c (1,2, "string")
> vect
[1] "1"     "2"     "string"
> write.table(vect, file="/home/sampleuser/sample.txt", append= FALSE, sep= "|")
```

However, since `vect` is a vector of string now, opening the file has following contents being in quoted form as:

```
"x"
"1"|"1"
"2"|"2"
"3"|"string"
```

Is it not possible to restore the data types of entries `1` and `2` being treated as numeric value instead of string. So my expected result is:

```
"x"
"1"|1
"2"|2
"3"|"string"
```

also, I am assuming the left side values "1", "2" and "3" are vector indexes? I did not understand how the first line is "x"?

Comment: A vector must contain all of the same data type.  If you want to mix and match you should use a list.

Comment: Why the first line is `"x"` is explained in the "Arguments" section of `?write.table`, specifically the `col.names` argument...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if simply removing all the quotes from the output file will solve your problem? That's easy: Add `quote=FALSE` to your `write.table()` call.

```
write.table(vect, file="/home/sampleuser/sample.txt", 
            append=FALSE, sep="|", quote=FALSE)

x
1|1
2|2
3|string
```

Also, you can get rid of the column and row names if you like. But now your separator character doesn't appear because you have a one-column table.

```
write.table(vect, file="/home/sampleuser/sample.txt", append=FALSE, sep="|",
            quote=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)

1
2
string
```

Comment: But then none of the strings will be marked as such, right? I guess it depends if the goal is output that looks a specific way, or having variables stored using the data type you want.

Answer (score 1):

For vectors and matrices, R requires everything to have the same data type. By default, R will coerce all of the data in the vector/matrix into the same format. R will coerce more specific types of data into less specific data types. In this case, any of the items stored in your vector can be reasonably represented as type "character", so it will automatically coerce the numeric parts of the vector to fit that data type.

As @Dason said, you're better off using a list if this isn't something you want.

Alternatively, you can use a data.frame, which lets you store different datatypes in different columns (internally, R stores data.frames as lists, so it makes sense that this would be another option).